# python selenium to click a button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

New to selenium.
Trying to click the "Reviews" in below chart.
I've tried solutions below. It works but Python throws exceptions after clicking "review". Hope someone can shed some light on why Python throws the exception and how to work around it?
The trace as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-53ed02f5557e>", line 1, in <module>
    browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.eiCell.cell.reviews").click()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=https%3A//.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi%3Bsrc%3D%3Btype%3Dinvmedia%3Bcat%3D%3Bu1%3D3f32e44c-d5d6-4d78-a817-7c9e0dd561a0%3Bord%3D8823339925721%3B%7Eoref%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.glassdoor.com%252FReviews%252FGoogle-Reviews-E9079.htm%3F&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20.fls.doubleclick.net.

    # code
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe')
    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/index.htm'
    browser.get(url)
    browser.find_element_by_id('KeywordSearch').send_keys('google')
    browser.find_element_by_id('HeroSearchButton').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    # click the review button
    # below code works but throw an exception after clicking "review".
    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1]) 
    browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".eiCell.cell.reviews").click() 

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="eiCell cell reviews" and contains(text(),"Reviews")]')`

Comment: Also try `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="subtle" and contains(text(),"Reviews")]')` or `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="subtle" and contains(text(),"Reviews")]/parent::a')`

Comment: What was the result when you tried those three methods? Please edit your question and add that info since it's important and will potentially help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element has multiple classes you should use:

```
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".eiCell.cell.reviews").click()
```

Comment: it gives "Message: Unable to locate element" error..I update my post to show the whole script.

Comment: @Lisa It should work fine, I tried your code, it seems the page is opening another browser's tab, then selenium is trying to locate the element in the other tab.

Comment: it searches "Google" first, and the result shows in another tab. On the result page I want to click "review". You run the code and it works fine?

Comment: I know what you want, you have to first tell selenium to focus on the tab you want to interact with, try `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])`, before trying my code. Sorry, it should be: `browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1])` , because thats your variable!! =)

Comment: You can even do `browser.close()` and then do the finding `browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".eiCell.cell.reviews").click()`

Comment: @Lisa Please let me know if that worked, I tested it and it did for me!

Comment: I tested your solution: browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1]); browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".eiCell.cell.reviews").click() The browser does clicj "review" tab and load the page that I want, however, it throw an exception afterwards: do you see the exception? selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=https%3A//.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi%3Bsrc%3D%3Btype%3Dinvmedia%3Bcat%3D%3Bu1%3D8a5dfe81-ce3b-492c-b1be-a99501e1e7d4%3Bord%3D4878842793749%3B%7Eoref%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.glassdoor...

Comment: I've updated the post. Please take a look. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with link text and partial link text is that they expect the text to actually be contained in the `A` tag. In this case, the text is contained in the `SPAN` that is a child of the `A` tag so they fail. The middle case, by class name, didn't work because you can only specify a single class name and you provided 3. In a case like this, you can use a CSS selector to specify the `A` tag like

```
a.eiCell.cell.reviews
```

or an XPath to specify the `SPAN` that contains the 'Reviews' text

```
//span[.='Reviews'][@class='subtle']
```

Either should work. I prefer the CSS selector since CSS selectors are faster and better supported on various browsers but if it doesn't work, try the XPath.

Comment: I am **not downvoting your effort and Answer** to help out the OP but isn't it confusing that first you have mentioned `CSS selectors are faster and better supported on various browsers` but next you are saying `if it doesn't work, try the XPath`. Do you essentially mean that there are some `XPath` which can't be expressed through `CSS`? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes, any locator that looks for contained text cannot be done with a CSS selector but can only be done with XPath (outside of text inside an `A` tag using link or partial link text). It's basically one of the very few reasons to use XPath locators.

Comment: Can you refer me to a sample HTML please from where `CSS` selector is unable to pull out the `contained text`? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no CSS selector that can locate an element by contained text, no matter the HTML. You can refer to this [W3C reference page for CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) to see what all they *can* do.

Comment: Why are you confined to `contained text` only? `CSS selector` is supposed to work with a lot other attributes like `class` & others. I don't see a reason for proper `CSS selector` to not to work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I think I grabbed this link a lot earlier from one of your Answers :) I am still working on it. Thanks again.

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm not... that's why I offered the first (and my preferred) option, a CSS selector. But... if that didn't work for some reason, there was the option to find the element by contained text, assuming it's unique on the page. Using XPath locators to find elements by their contained text is just another way, sometimes the only way, to uniquely locate an element on the page.

Comment: @DebanjanB No problem. I keep links around like that to refer to from time to time when I need some CSS selector that I don't use often. It's also very useful to pass on to others to learn more since I found it very helpful when I was learning CSS selectors.

Comment: I got error "Message: Unable to locate element".. I updated the post to have the whole script

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You can use the following line of code to click on "Reviews" in the chart.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='eiCell cell reviews']//span[@class='subtle']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Got error:
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@class='eiCell cell reviews']//span[@class='subtle']